# Using a clause as a sentence's subject

Tags: sentence-construction

> Recently several audio recordings claimed racist riots on Dec 7 and 8 will occur have gone viral telling people not to leave the house on those two days.

1. Is "Recently....Will occur" a clause ?
2. Is it grammatically correct to use a clause as a subject of a sentence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is "several audio recordings":

> several audio recordings have gone viral

"claimed that riots on Dec 7 and 8 will occur" is a participle phrase describing "several audio recordings", but it's incorrect: the past participle **claimed** needs to be replaced with a present participle **claiming**. Past participles are permissible in participle phrases, but they make a passive mood phrase, and we need an active mood phrase here. Also, the prepositional phrase **on Dec 7 and 8** should follow the verb that it applies to (occur). The revised adjectival phrase is then:

> ...claiming that riots will occur on Dec 7 and 8"

If the audio recordings tell people not to leave the house, that should follow the other participle phrase:

> ...claiming that riots will occur on Dec 7 and 8 and telling people not to leave the house on those two days

The complete sentence is therefore:

> Several audio recordings claiming that riots will occur on Dec 7 and 8 and telling people not to leave the house on those two days have gone viral

This sentence is still not clear, because the adjectival clause is massive. This would be better:

> Several audio recordings have gone viral, claiming that riots will occur on Dec 7 and 8 and telling people not to leave the house on those two days

Comment: Got it . Here a few more questions -  Can the "audio recordings" do the claim as in "Several audio recordings claimed that a riot will occur on monday" ? In English, can a clause be used as a subject ?

Comment: An article can claim something, a verbal statement can claim something, but IMHO an audio recording can't claim something. No, a clause can't be used as a subject: you generally use a phrase containing a gerund or a to-infinitive. "**running across the road without looking** is dangerous", "**to sell the shares now** would be a big mistake".